# Disabling UI while in a modal (Python API)

Tags: python

I think I have seen this in another add-on but I have been unable to actually find it again when trying to reproduce the effect. Basically, when I enter my own custom modal operation I want to darken everything but what is contained within the viewport. My hypothesis is maybe they grab the ui and make .active to False across the board?

I don't think I want 'BLOCKING', or 'GRAB_CURSOR' (no mouse wrapping). I just want the buttons to be un-pressable.

This screenshot shows what I mean (just imagine you entered a modal operator lol).
[image]

Any help is appreciated.